# How to implicitly cast custom IEnumerable in foreach?

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

I want the `var` in my `foreach` loop to implicit cast the items of my custom `IEnumerable`. It loops over an internal `Dictionary` and is mostly a wrapper. I tried the generic and the nongeneric `IEnumerable`.

I want to understand what is needed to support an implicit cast in the `foreach` loop.

```
public class Bewerbung : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
        protected Dictionary<string, string> internDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return internDic.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return internDic.GetEnumerator() ;
        }
}
```

```
            var bewerbung = new Bewerbung();
            foreach (var testi in bewerbung)
            {

            }
```

`testi` is always an object and not a `KeyValuePair`, like it should be.

I know that I could use an explicit cast for practical use but I want to understand whats wrong about my approach. Other `IEnumerable`s can be implicitly casted, why doesn't this work for my custom class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`foreach` is a fun beast - it is duck-typed whenever possible (meaning: it doesn't actually need the `IEnumerable[<T>]` API if a `public {something} GetEnumerator()` method exists), and in your case, the `public` method is the non-generic one. So... reverse that:

```cs
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return internDic.GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
{
    return internDic.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Note also that it is common to just proxy the explicit implementation to the `public` one to avoid maintenance errors, i.e.

```cs
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    => GetEnumerator();

public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    => internDic.GetEnumerator();
```

You could even expose the custom dictionary enumerator if you want to optimize for that:

```cs
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    => GetEnumerator();

IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.GetEnumerator()
    => GetEnumerator();

public Dictionary<string, string>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    => internDic.GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: @MarcGravell, so, we could inherit `Bewerbung` just from `IEnumerable`, right?

Comment: @DmitryStepanov you *could*, but it would be a bad idea - LINQ - and just good practice etc - expects `IEnumerable<T>`, not just `IEnumerable`

Comment: @DmitryStepanov but to be clear: you don't need to implement **any** interfaces to be able to use `foreach` - just having `GetEnumerator()` by itself is enough